# Regex: how to extract text until end of string with multiple new lines?

Tags: javascript, regex

I want it to match each of the text and flexible enough to read multiple lines instead of a single line.

Text single input example

```
383 Bukit Timah Road #01-09B Alocassia Apartments Singapore 259727
```

Text with multiple lines example

```
383 Bukit Timah Road 
#01-09B Alocassia Apartments 
Singapore 259727

448 Ang Mo Kio 
Avenue 10 #01-1693 
Singapore 560448

383 Bukit Timah Road 
#01-09B Alocassia Apartments 
Singapore 259727
```

Regex:

```
(\d+ .*\d{6}\b)
```

Comment: What language/tool are you using? From the [regex tag info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/regex/info): "Since regular expressions are not fully standardized, all questions with this tag should also include a tag specifying the applicable programming language or tool."

Comment: im sorry, i've edited my post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `[^]` (specific to JavaScript Regex) to match any character including linebreaks

The regex is:

```
^(\d+ [^]*?\b\d{6})$
```

[Demo & explanation](https://regex101.com/r/I4O4Kt/1)

```js
var test = [
`383 Bukit Timah Road #01-09B Alocassia Apartments Singapore 259727`,
`383 Bukit Timah Road 
#01-09B Alocassia Apartments 
Singapore 259727`,
`448 Ang Mo Kio 
Avenue 10 #01-1693 
Singapore 560448`,
`383 Bukit Timah Road 
#01-09B Alocassia Apartments 
Singapore 259727`,
`123 blah blah`,
`blah blah 123456`,
`123 blah blah 1234567`
];
console.log(test.map(function (a) {
  return a + ' :' + /^(\d+ [^]*?\b\d{6})$/.test(a);
}));
```

Comment: This is perfect! Thank you so much. I will give this answer to you instead

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking for is the `s` flag (single line: dot matches newline).
https://regex101.com/r/ZTP1hC/1

Comment: what if i have multiple addresses? it seems to be matching multiple addresses under a single match

Comment: I believe does not necessarily have to be but flexible enough to read with/without the new lines

Comment: if you want to match multiple instances (addresses in this case) make sure to match as little as possible between the numbers using the `?` after the `*`. So `/(\d+ .*?\d{6}\b)/gs`